# Getting java.io.NotSerializableException while mapping a JavaRDD

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

Following is the code which is leading to java.io.NotSerializableException when I try to dispatch the job to executors.

```
    JavaRDD<Row> rddToWrite = dataToWrite.toJavaRDD();
    JavaRDD<String> stringRdd = rddToWrite.map(new Function<Row, String>() {

        /**
         * Serial Version Id
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6766320395808127072L;

        @Override
        public String call(Row row) throws Exception {
            return row.mkString(dataFormat.getDelimiter());
        }
    });
```

However, when I do the following, the task is serialized successfully :

```
JavaRDD<Row> rddToWrite = dataToWrite.toJavaRDD();
List<String> dataList = rddToWrite.collect().stream().parallel()
                           .map(row -> row.mkString(dataFormat.getDelimiter()))
                           .collect(Collectors.<String>toList());
JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sessionContext.getSparkContext());
JavaRDD<String> stringRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(dataList);
```

Can anyone please help me point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:
dataFormat is a private member field in the class where the function containing this code is written. It's an object of a class DataFormat which defines two fields, namely, spark dataformat (e.g. "com.databricks.spark.csv") and the delimiter (e.g. "\t").

Comment: What's `dataFormat`?

Comment: Is `dataFormat` a local variable or a field of the enclosing class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous class created by `new Function ...` needs a reference to the enclosing instance, and serializing the function requires serializing the enclosing instance, including `dataFormat` *and* all other fields. If that class is not marked as `Serializable`, or has any non-serializable non-`transient` fields, it won't work. And even if it does, it silently performs worse than necessary.

Unfortunately, to fully work around this you need to create a named static inner class (or just a separate class), and it can't even be local (because neither anonymous nor [local classes in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) can be static):

```
static class MyFunction extends Function<Row, String> {
    private String delimiter;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6766320395808127072L;

    MyFunction(String delimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    @Override
    public String call(Row row) throws Exception {
        return row.mkString(delimiter);
    }
}
```

And then

```
JavaRDD<String> stringRdd = rddToWrite.map(new MyFunction(dataFormat.getDelimiter()));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you access `dataFormat`, it means `this.dataFormat`.
So spark will try to serialize `this` and encounter the `NotSerializableException`.

Try make a local copy like:

```
DataFormat dataformat = this.dataformat;
JavaRDD<Row> rddToWrite = dataToWrite.toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<String> stringRdd = rddToWrite.map(new Function<Row, String>() ...
```

For more information, see
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#passing-functions-to-spark

Comment: At least in a quick test, even an anonymous class which doesn't access any methods or fields of the enclosing instance still has a reference to it, and so will try to serialize it. Maybe I did something wrong, though...

Comment: Alexey is right! This was still serializing the enclosing instance. Was causing same issue.

Comment: Yes he is right. I have some misunderstand about anonymous function in java.